# Unmarshal() method of JAXB returns an empty object

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

Note: this project uses JAXB which is deprecated in Java 9. You need to have Java 8 in your JAVA_HOME instead of Java 9. The POM file is set up so all the dependencies should work fine. I was able to build the program with Maven. I'm just making sure the features work fine.

I'm working on updating this project to newer version of scribejava and async-http-client. Here's my repository (I'm working on this):
https://github.com/khoanguyen0791/tradeking

I've traced the error to unmarshal() method. The input exists, but that method returns an empty object. Can someone explain why it returns an empty JAXB object and how to fix it? The xml schema is in my repository.

```
static public <T> T getElement(InputSource source, String path, String root,
        Class<T> clazz) throws Exception {

    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(path);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(source);
    Element element = doc.getDocumentElement();
    System.out.println(element == null);



    if (root != null) {
        NodeList nodeList = element.getChildNodes();
        for (int j = 0; j < nodeList.getLength(); j++) {
            System.out.println(j);

            Node childNode = nodeList.item(j);

            if (childNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                if (childNode.getNodeName().equals(root)) {
                    element = (Element) childNode;

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    NodeList nodes = element.getChildNodes();
     for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            System.out.println("" + nodes.item(i).getTextContent());
         }
    JAXBElement<T> t = jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(element, clazz);

    return t.getValue();
}
```

Comment: Which version of Java 8 are you using?  I'm aware there was a change in Java 8 about version 101 which made JAXB namespace-sensitive: if namespaces in the XML being unmarshalled and the objects to unmarshal into didn't match, unmarshalling no longer happened.  Would it be possible to edit your question to include sample XML and the classes that the XML is being unmarshalled into?

Comment: sudo apt-get oracle-java8-installer. There is something wrong with the unmarshal() method. It return an object without any content.

Comment: That `apt-get` command doesn't tell me which version of Java 8 you are using; `java -version` should. The object-without-content behaviour is exactly what I've seen with this namespace issue I mentioned.  See a [similar question I recently answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49885939).  As before, can you please edit your question to include some sample XML that fails to unmarshal and the classes that the XML is being unmarshalled into.

Answer (score 0):

You must be using the wrong JAXBUtils dependency( Or else the wrong version no.). make sure to add a breakpoint at,
**return getElement(packageName, response.toString(), root, clazz);**
and debug the code.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I've checked and the issue is in unmarshall() method. Somehow it returns null even with proper input.